# Why doesn't this Makefile work?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this C file:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And this Makefile

```
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
EXEC=hello.exe

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)

.PHONY: all
```

When I do `make` it doesn't create my target `hello.exe` why?

```
$ make
cc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
```

It doesn't either work with `hello.exe`:

```
$ make hello.exe
make: Nothing to be done for 'hello.exe'.
```

And `hello.exe` doesn't exist:

```
$ ls hello.exe
ls: cannot access 'hello.exe': No such file or directory
```

I use this version of GNU Make

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**EDIT**

It actually works when I name my executable the same of any of my files. So it works with:

```
EXEC=hello
```

See:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
cc   hello.o   -o hello
```

That said I don't understand why it only works that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with `hello.exe` does not work because `make` has no implicit rule to tell it how to turn a bunch of `*.o` into a single `*.exe`.

But it *does* have implicit rules (at least those specified by POSIX) to turn `hello.c` into `hello.o` and link into `hello`.

Remember, Unix is not DOS. Forget the `.exe` when you're on Unix.